# RubyAmf and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubyamf

I have recently been trying to upgrade my app form Rails 2.3.8 to newly-releases Rails 3.

After going through fixing some Rails 3 RubyAMF doesn't seem to work:

```
>>>>>>>> RubyAMF >>>>>>>>> #<RubyAMF::Actions::PrepareAction:0x1649924> took: 0.00017 secs
The action '#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x15c0cf0>' could not be found for DaysController
/Users/tammam56/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:114:in `process'
/Users/tammam56/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in `process'
```

It doesn't seem to be able to find the proper controller. Might have to do with new changes in Rails 3 Router. Do you know how to go about finding the root cause of the problem and/or trying to fix it?

I'm pasting code from RubyAMF where this is happening (Exception happens at the line: @service.process(req, res)):

```
      #invoke the service call
      def invoke
        begin
          # RequestStore.available_services[@amfbody.service_class_name] ||=
          @service =  @amfbody.service_class_name.constantize.new #handle on service

        rescue Exception => e
          puts e.message
          puts e.backtrace
          raise RUBYAMFException.new(RUBYAMFException.UNDEFINED_OBJECT_REFERENCE_ERROR, "There was an error loading the service class #{@amfbody.service_class_name}")
        end

        if @service.private_methods.include?(@amfbody.service_method_name.to_sym)
          raise RUBYAMFExc

eption.new(RUBYAMFException.METHOD_ACCESS_ERROR, "The method {#{@amfbody.service_method_name}} in class {#{@amfbody.service_class_file_path}} is declared as private, it must be defined as public to access it.")
    elsif !@service.public_methods.include?(@amfbody.service_method_name.to_sym)
      raise RUBYAMFException.new(RUBYAMFException.METHOD_UNDEFINED_METHOD_ERROR, "The method {#{@amfbody.service_method_name}} in class {#{@amfbody.service_class_file_path}} is not declared.")
    end

    #clone the request and response and alter it for the target controller/method
    req = RequestStore.rails_request.clone
    res = RequestStore.rails_response.clone

    #change the request controller/action targets and tell the service to process. THIS IS THE VOODOO. SWEET!
    controller = @amfbody.service_class_name.gsub("Controller","").underscore
    action     = @amfbody.service_method_name
    req.parameters['controller'] = req.request_parameters['controller'] = req.path_parameters['controller'] = controller
    req.parameters['action']     = req.request_parameters['action']     = req.path_parameters['action']     = action
    req.env['PATH_INFO']         = req.env['REQUEST_PATH']              = req.env['REQUEST_URI']            = "#{controller}/#{action}"
    req.env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = 'application/x-amf,' + req.env['HTTP_ACCEPT'].to_s

    #set conditional helper
    @service.is_amf = true
    @service.is_rubyamf = true

    #process the request
    rubyamf_params = @service.rubyamf_params = {}
    if @amfbody.value && !@amfbody.value.empty?
      @amfbody.value.each_with_index do |item,i|
        rubyamf_params[i] = item
      end
    end

    # put them by default into the parameter hash if they opt for it
    rubyamf_params.each{|k,v| req.parameters[k] = v} if ParameterMappings.always_add_to_params

    begin
      #One last update of the parameters hash, this will map custom mappings to the hash, and will override any conflicting from above
      ParameterMappings.update_request_parameters(@amfbody.service_class_name, @amfbody.service_method_name, req.parameters, rubyamf_params, @amfbody.value)
    rescue Exception => e
      raise RUBYAMFException.new(RUBYAMFException.PARAMETER_MAPPING_ERROR, "There was an error with your parameter mappings: {#{e.message}}")
    end
    @service.process(req, res)

    #unset conditional helper
    @service.is_amf = false
    @service.is_rubyamf = false
    @service.rubyamf_params = rubyamf_params # add the rubyamf_args into the controller to be accessed

    result = RequestStore.render_amf_results

    #handle FaultObjects
    if result.class.to_s == 'FaultObject' #catch returned FaultObjects - use this check so we don't have to include the fault object module
      e = RUBYAMFException.new(result['code'], result['message'])
      e.payload = result['payload']
      raise e
    end

    #amf3
    @amfbody.results = result
    if @amfbody.special_handling == 'RemotingMessage'
      @wrapper = generate_acknowledge_object(@amfbody.get_meta('messageId'), @amfbody.get_meta('clientId'))
      @wrapper["body"] = result
      @amfbody.results = @wrapper
    end
    @amfbody.success! #set the success response uri flag (/onResult)
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best suggestion is to try [rails3-amf](http://github.com/warhammerkid/rails3-amf). It currently is severely lacking in features in comparison to RubyAMF, but it does work and I'm adding new features as soon as they are requested or I have time.