# Adobe Flex/Air talks with Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, air, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I found RubyAmf and RestfulX but it doesn't work for me with Rails 3.2.
There is some another solution out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Rails3-AMF](https://github.com/warhammerkid/rails3-amf).  [Answer stolen from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603628/rubyamf-and-rails-3)